# ¿Cómo manejar cuando no existe la variable que intento pasar a una ruta en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, array, blade, datos

tengo el siguiente problema:

Necesito pasar una variable, un arreglo que contiene más arreglos dentro con los datos de cada portafolio, el cuál, quiero mostrar en la vista portafolio.blade.php. En el archivo web.php he definido la siguiente ruta:

```
Route::view('portfolio', 'portfolio', compact('portafolios'))->name('portfolio');
```

Esta debería pasar el siguiente arreglo:

```
$portfolios = [
    ['title' => 'Proyecto #1', 'created_at' => '03-02-2021'],
    ['title' => 'Proyecto #2',  'created_at' => '03-03-2021'],
    ['title' => 'Proyecto #3',  'created_at' => '03-04-2021'],
    ['title' => 'Proyecto #4', 'created_at' => '03-05-2021'],
];

// Este es solo un ejemplo
```

Todo bien. Si la variable está definida la puedo mostrar sin problemas en la vista de la siguiente manera:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('title', 'Portfolio')

@section('container')
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    @if($portfolios)
        <ul>
            @foreach ($portfolios as $portfolioItem)
                <li>{{ $portfolioItem['title'] }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @else
        <p>No hay proyectos para mostrar</p>
    @endif
@endsection
```

Si la variable `$portfolios` no está defininida, Laravel me arroja el siguiente error

```
ErrorException
compact(): Undefined variable: portafolios
http://app.test/portfolio
```

Entonces, quiero que cuando no esté definida la variable me arroje el mensaje de que no hay datos para mostrar. Ojo que es cuando no existe la variable, no cuando el arreglo está vacío. Buscando en la documentación de Laravel encontré la directiva blade @isset, que verifica que exista la variable. Intente hacer esa validación en la vista pero de todas maneras me sigue arrojando el mismo error. Con @isset quedaría así la vista:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('title', 'Portfolio')

@section('container')
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    @isset($portfolios)
        <ul>
            @foreach ($portfolios as $portfolioItem)
                <li>{{ $portfolioItem['title'] }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @else
        <p>No hay proyectos para mostrar</p>
    @endisset
@endsection
```

Intento encontrar una solución pero no consigo hacerlo, el arreglo está definido en el archivo web.php en la carpeta routes. Si alguien tiene más experiencia al respecto y me pueda ayudar con esta inquietud, estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: el @ isset($portafolios), cambialo por @ if(isset($portafolios)), recuerda cambiar el @ endisset por @ endif

Comment: Yo te sugeriría que para una mejor práctica, no valides este tipo de cosas directamente desde una vista blade. Deberías de tener una ruta que vaya hacia un método de un controlador en donde puedas validar esa información, donde en caso de cumplirse, procedas a mostrar esa vista, caso contrario puedas realizar otra acción. No entiendo por qué quieres validar todo desde web.php y a mi parecer no es una buena idea

Comment: @FernandoTorres Sí, sé que son malas prácticas. Lo estoy haciendo simplemente con fines de refozarmiento y educativos. Y lo del controlador esta muy bien, solo que estoy experimentando con las rutas y vistas directamente para aprender a dominarlas de manera profesional.

Comment: Ojalá pudieras seguir las mejores prácticas para poder hacer las cosas en su lugar correcto. Por otro lado, para lograr solucionar el problema que tienes, te sugiero echarle un vistazo a esta información de la documentación oficial de Laravel en donde encontrarás formas correctas de validar el tipo de información que manejas en las vistas blades https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements

Comment: puedes revisar si la variable es `portfolios` o `portafolios`? En la pregunta las mezclas

Comment: portfolios es la variable me confundí con el idioma pero está en inglés.